# How to add block to "add/edit" content page?

Tags: blocks

is there a way to add views block to add/edit content pages? I have two content types and one of them has Taxonomy term baste with unique terms (one term per node), when creating new node I want to have block with unused terms. I tried to accomplish this using Markup module but no success, and Display suite and Panels didn't worked.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to display a block on node add/edit pages in Drupal 8:

Go to `Structure -> Blocks`.  Select the block layout page for the theme you use to add/edit nodes. This is usually the admin theme, but it may also be the standard theme for your site if you want to display the block to non-admin users. If you want to show the block to both admin and non-admin users, you may need to configure the block settings (as described below) for both the admin theme and the standard theme.

On the block layout page, click **Edit** on the block you want to display.

Under **Visibility**, click **Pages**.

In the text field, enter:

```
/node/add/*
/node/*/edit
```

For Drupal 7, don't use the first slash:

```
node/add/*
node/*/edit
```

The `*` is a wildcard that says "any content/value can go here."

Then check the radio button for **Show for the listed pages**.

If you also want to limit the block to only show for certain content types, you can use the **Content types** option above **Pages**.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that you need to do this on the blocks page for the admin theme (most people use admin theme for node add/edit and the block layout defaults to the front end theme)

Comment: @Clive Good point, that's definitely a gotcha.  Updated.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Thank You very very very much, I have created so may sites in Drupal, and never felt so dumb about "problem" like this. This is so simple and clean solution. Thank you once again.